# How do I display different content on the same content blocks in Drupal?

Tags: drupal, panels, drupal-blocks

I am trying to build 10 pages that have the same structure (4 square content blocks on the right sidebar, and the general content on the left side). I am trying to build it so that the block structure remains the same on each page, but the content within the blocks is different. I tried doing this using the generic blocks provided by Drupal, but this is tedious and requires me to display the block only on each page individually, and then create a new one on the next page. Is there any easier way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [views](http://drupal.org/project/views) with contextual filters see this [video](http://vimeo.com/22180500)